# Outputting a detect() in a case_when mutate so I can output the column&row where first element in a different vector that meets a condition

Tags: r, indexing, case, purrr, mutate

My current code:

```r
labs <- %>%
   group_by(id) %>% 
   mutate(
     binary2 = case_when(ymd(date1)>ymd(min(date1))+days(140) & ymd(date1) <=ymd(min(date1))+days(365) ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0), #the condition
     date2 = case_when(binary1==1 & n() > 1 & any(binary2==1)~
           purrr::detect(date1, ~ binary2 == 1)], 
           # the intention is to call the first date1 that exists when binary 2 is 
           # 1 and place it where the first row of the id is located.

           TRUE ~as.POSIXct(0)), #just so the case_when is in the correct case
  
)
```

input data:

| id | date1 | binary1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021/01/01 | 1 |
| 1 | 2021/10/01 | 1 |
| 1 | 2021/11/01 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021/02/01 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021/03/01 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021/03/02 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021/10/01 | 1 |
| 2 | 2023/12/01 | 1 |
| 3 | 2021/02/01 | 0 |
| 3 | 2023/02/01 | 1 |
| 4 | 2021/02/01 | 0 |
| 5 | 2021/02/01 | 0 |

output data:

| id | date1 | binary1 | binary2 | date2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021/01/01 | 1 | 0 | 2021/10/01 |
| 1 | 2021/10/01 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2021/11/01 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2021/02/01 | 1 | 0 | 2021/11/01 |
| 2 | 2021/03/01 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2021/03/02 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2021/11/01 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2023/12/01 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 2021/02/01 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 2023/02/01 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 2021/02/01 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 2021/02/01 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

In summary, I want to be able to retrieve the first date that falls within more than 140 days and less than 365 days from the first date, and put it into that values' row. I am open to alternative solutions.

Edit: had the wrong variable name in my function.

Edit: The most common error I keep having is:
! `.f()` must return a single `TRUE` or `FALSE`, not a logical vector.

Basically, when I try to run detect() in a group_by() something seems off. I am unsure why, but I will keep trying on this. I have narrowed down my data through a lot of filtering to try to make the logic as simple as possible, but it does not seem to work. I will try merging and other filters to see if there is another workaround.

Edit: Several days later, I figured out this would suffice as a means of finding the first past the goal post:
[How to find first element of a group that fulfill a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52342744/how-to-find-first-element-of-a-group-that-fulfill-a-condition)

Basically I did this:

```
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(first = as.numeric(row_number() == min(row_number()[date1+140 >= date2 <= date1+365]))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Hi Tom, welcome to SO. Great you found a solution. This site encourages people to self-answer so do post your solution as an answer. However, there are issues with your question: there are errors in both codeblocks, and the date values in your input table don't match the dates in the output example. Questions and answers on SO are expected to be reproducible. Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example) for more info. Poorly formatted questions will attract downvotes. Thanks